# How to Correctly Call C++ DLL from C# using Correct Parameter Types

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I have been provided with a DLL which is to be called by C# et al. The DLL contains two methods as follows

```
extern "C" {
   __declspec(dllexport) BSTR GroupInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile, bool bDiagErr, bool bProcErr);
   __declspec(dllexport) void G();
} 

class GrouperServer {
public:
   BSTR GroupInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile, bool bDiagErr, bool bProcErr);
   void G();
}

BSTR GrouperServer::GroupInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile, bool bDiagErr, bool bProcErr) {
   CString strResult = "";
   char* sz;
   SetVars(bDiagErr, bProcErr);

   if (sz = ::GroupInit((char*)bstrIniFile, 1))
      strResult = sz;
   return strResult.AllocSysString();
}

void G() {
   MessageBox(0, "And text here", "MessageBox caption", MB_OK);
}
```

I am attempting to call these DLLs from C# by first defining the class:

```
public class GrouperServer {
    [DllImport("GrouperServer.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void G();

    [DllImport("GrouperServer.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public static extern string GroupInit(
        string strCmdFile, bool bAllowBadDiagCodes, bool bAllowBadProcCodes);
}
```

and doing

```
this.strCommandFilePath = "C:\\MyDir\\MyCommandFile.txt";
Grouper.GrouperServer.G();
Grouper.GrouperServer.GroupInit(this.strCommandFilePath, true, true);
```

The call to method `G()` works and I get a message box, but for the call to `GroupInit()`, I get

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in DrGroupIN.exe. Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'GroupInit' in DLL 'GrouperServer.dll'.

How can I call the second method `GrouInit(...)` with the correct parameters in this case?

---

**Edit 1.**

I have also tried

```
[DllImport("GrouperServer.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr GroupInit(
    string strCmdFile, bool bAllowBadDiagCodes, bool bAllowBadProcCodes);
```

where this is called via:

```
IntPtr ptr = Grouper.GrouperServer.GroupInit(this.strCommandFilePath, true, true);
string strString = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(ptr);
Marshal.FreeBSTR(ptr);
```

But this too throws the error above.

**Edit 2.**

I have also tried

```
[DllImport("GrouperServer.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public static extern string GroupInit(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]string strCmdFile, 
    bool bAllowBadDiagCodes, 
    bool bAllowBadProcCodes);
```

But this too throws the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as though you cannot call this DLL using C#. The DLL exports member functions of a class. And you cannot instantiate that class.

I can see the following options:

1. Ask the DLL vendor to export either static member functions, or non-member functions. These should then be accessible using p/invoke.
2. Write a mixed mode C++/CLI wrapper around the DLL. This wrapper can readily consume the unmanaged DLL. In turn it can then expose a managed ref class that wraps the functionality. The C++/CLI wrapper can then be added as a reference to the C# project.

---

That said, these declarations seem to be in conflict:

```
extern "C" {
   __declspec(dllexport) BSTR GroupInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile, bool bDiagErr, bool bProcErr);
   __declspec(dllexport) void G();
} 

class GrouperServer {
public:
   BSTR GroupInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile, bool bDiagErr, bool bProcErr);
   void G();
}
```

The first pair of declarations seem to be non-member functions. But they are followed by a class with member functions having the same names. You do need to be clear which functions you are attempting to call.

Perhaps the DLL already contains non-member functions that wrap up the member functions. In which case you just need to find out the names by which they are exported. Use Dependency Walker to do that.

So, how to declare the p/invoke. You need to know the character set in use, and the name by which the function is exported. Let's assume Unicode. The p/invoke would be:

```
[DllImport("GrouperServer.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    EntryPoint = "<exported name goes here>")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public static extern string GroupInit(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string strCmdFile, 
    bool bAllowBadDiagCodes, 
    bool bAllowBadProcCodes
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. I have been given the source C++ code yesterday. The core library is written in C and prior to being given this code, it had a COM C++ wrapper class. This was massively slow when called from C# (1,000s of calls as quick as possible required). So the author gave me the C code so I could wrap it in some way. I have never done this before so would appreciate any further advice you may be able to afford me? What do you mean by 'mixed mode C++/CLI wrapper'? Thanks very much for your time... Ps. the `G()` method invokes okay!?

Comment: Create a C++ CLR class library project in VS. This will compile to a .net managed assembly. You can use C++/CLI code to consume the native DLL. Include its header file and link to its import library. A bit of websearch should see you home.

Comment: Since your answer is right, I won't post a new one but I think the error is really due to the fact that the code declares(and export) an extern named `GroupInit` but does not define it. So the method is not in the DLL hence the exception. It is not related to the class member function.

Comment: @EricFortin I can see a definition in the code in the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry, I understand how to create the C++ CLR library, but it was the 'mixed mode' statement I am not familiar with. I would like to be able to use the C++ wrapper DLL from other languages too ideally. I understand your advice and it is good, but I am still not sure why the `G()` [test method] invokes but the `GroupInit(...)` does not...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see the definition for the member one but not for the free function one like the G function.

Comment: @EricFortin I see what you are saying here. I am doing `GrouperServer::GroupInit(...)` and I need `GroupInit(...)`.

Comment: Like I said the answer was mostly right in his suggestions, I just wanted to point out why there was the exception.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for your time here and indeed the informative edit... This was the problem. I have not written C++ for 5 years and am rusty as hell. One last piece of advice if you would be so kind; Why do I have to specify the `EntryPoint` if I am declaring the correct C++ method name?

Comment: You use `EntryPoint` if the exported name differs from the name you want to use in the C# code. Otherwise you omit it.